# Core Data multiplying number of objects in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When I save a `Recording` object and then go over to check the `UITableView` in the other tab, there's three more instances then when I originally saved it. Every time I add a **single** new recording, the number of recordings added to the `UITableView` is more than before. As in, by the third or fourth new `Recording` I add, I have 20 or 30 rows in the table view. Even when I quite the app and open it up again, the extra `Recording` objects are still there. **Why is the number of objects `Core Data` saves increasing exponentially, when I'm only trying to save one?**

**This is the code that gets called (by `NSNotificationCenter`) to update the `UItableView`:**

```
NSLog(@"Updating");
_recordings = [recordingRepository getAllRecordings];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

**This is the code that `getAllRecordings` calls:**

```
-(NSArray*) getAllRecordings {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Recording" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor* sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateStarted" ascending:NO];
    NSArray* sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sort, nil];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {

    }
    return [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:fetchedObjects];
}
```

**This is the code that creates a new recording:**

```
+(Recording*) createNewAudioRecording {
    NSLog(@"New Recording");
    NSManagedObjectContext* managedObjectContext = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
    Recording* r = (Recording*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recording" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] saveContext];
    [r createRandomAddress];
    NSString* start = [[Recording createRandomAddress] absoluteString];
    NSString* withExtension = [start stringByAppendingString:@".caf"];
    r.url = withExtension;
    return r;
}
```

The `NSLog(@"New Recording")` only prints once, so I know that it is only creating one object (I think). `[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance]` is just the shared instance for retrieving the `CoreData` objects.

**This is the `[[[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] saveContext]` function:**

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] managedObjectContext];
NSLog(@"SAVING");
if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
    if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
}
```

Comment: implement `awakeFromInsert` of your `Recording` class and put a breakpoint in it and find out what code is responsible for creating the redundant objects

Comment: Tell us more about the notifications. I bet you're registering for notifications and never unregistering.

Comment: @TomHarrington Maybe i'm misunderstanding something, but why would I unregister? The notification is only sent out when a new recording is created, which I always want to respond to.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure, but your symptoms sound a lot like accidentally registering for the same notification more than once without ever unregistering. When that happens there are multiple observers who all get the notification. If they're all instances of the same class, they all do the same thing, which can lead to unwanted extra instances.

Comment: @TomHarrington Well, it's registered in the init method of the TableViewController

Comment: @TomHarrington I just confirmed that it's only registering once

Comment: Check the following:
How many objects does your fetch return ?  
The code you are using to populate the tableView ?
How many duplicates are there of each recording, the same for all or different ?